# How can I determine if an input sentence is consistent with a certain subject?

Tags: natural-language-processing

How can I determine if an input sentence is consistent with a certain subject?

For example, suppose I am given the following dataset.

```
| Subject       | User input           | Output |
|---------------|----------------------|--------|
| Dog ownership | I own a dog          | Yes    |
| Dog ownership | My dog is called Joe | Yes    |
| Dog ownership | I don't have a dog   | No     |
```

In the examples above, the subject "dog ownership" is consistent with the input sentences "I own a dog" and "My dog is called Joe" (because, if your dog is called Joe, then you also own a dog).

Answer (score 2):

If you have lots of training data, ANN's (deep learning) could quite possibly get you there.  But I have a hunch you might also get some mileage out of using something like a [rule induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_induction) approach.  Maybe something like [CN2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CN2_algorithm). I'd suggest at least reading up on those and see if you can see a way to apply that to your system.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have enough training data for ANN's, but I'm starting to think that I will need it. Since it will require a big amount of effort, I was waiting to be sure that getting this big set of data is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have collection of data or information, then you would like to ask questions about this data and machine should answer you.

I think you need first, data mining to export the meaning and relations in this data, then you can build your expert system that will answer you.

Comment: I do have some training data. Do you know any particular algorithm that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks are the one thing I would *not* recommend. Your problem fits into the domain of [predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), with some basic pattern recognition of the input sentences (assuming you only accept a certain type of sentences). You can do that without the need for masses of data.

First, transform your statement into a canonical representation, probably using first-order logic and simple pattern matching/string matching. For example,

```
I own a dog 

X own/owns a/an Y  

owns(I, dog)
```

Here you have a pattern "*X* own(s) a(n) *Y*", which you recognise in your user input. You then have a predicate *owns(X, Y)*, which you add to your database of statements. This database you can then query. For example, *Do I own a cat?* could fit a question pattern *Do/Does X own(s) a(n) Y?*, and you can search for *own(I, cat)* in your DB; you will not find it, so the answer is "No". If the question is "Do I own a dog?" you will find *owns(I, dog)* in your database and you can reply "Yes".

This is all rather 'old' technology, but I think you will find that you will get decent results much quicker than with machine learning or statistical methods, especially if you have not much data to begin with.

A further branch to look into would be [expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system). If you're thinking in terms of programming languages, then [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) would be well suited for this, but any language should do, really.